# How stat show a file size?

Tags: linux, terminal, stat

just curios how stat show a file size....
for example I have a file with only one letter in it

> echo a > test

when I do

> ```
>  stat test
> ```

I see Size: 2

but when I do

> ```
>  du -h test
> ```

I see 4.0K

So what I'm missing ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [du(1)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/du.1.html) manpage, `du` *estimates* disk usage, it doesn't show apparent file size, unless you pass `--apparent-size`.

It seems the estimation is based on the assumption of a 4096-byte disk allocation granularity. (Make a 4097-bytes-large file, `du` will report 8KiB, etc.).